# ui:repeat and c:foreach dont return the same organisation

Tags: primefaces, foreach, uirepeat

I have a loop that contains a list of properties
I would like to display this list on 2 columns, but I can not.
  they are displayed by unordered, against if I use c: For Each place of ui: repeat
the problem is resolved

```
<p:panel id="panlecart2" header ="Caracteristique selon la categorie" toggleable="true" rendered="true" style="width=900px;">            
            <h:panelGrid  id="panlecart" columns="2" cellpadding="5" rendered="true" style="width=900px;">                         
            <ui:repeat var="var1" value="#{composantbean.categorie.proprietes.toArray()}">            
            <h:outputText value="#{var1.nomProp }(#{var1.unite}  )"  />
            <h:inputText value="" />  

            </ui:repeat>             
         </h:panelGrid>
          </p:panel>
```

Haw can I fixe the problem .helpe please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could switch to using `<h:dataTable>` to iterate over the components:

```
<h:dataTable var="var1" value="#{composantbean.categorie.proprietes.toArray()}">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{var1.nomProp }(#{var1.unite}  )"  />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:inputText value="" />  
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Enclose it within a `<p:panel>` to make it work. Otherwise, make use of `<c:forEach>` as it's a good fit for your use case.

Comment: as I say .the problem of the c:foreach it not support ajax

Comment: Thx it is Fine now with h:dataTable .think you for your cooperation

Answer (score 1):

`ui:repeat` is rendered in a later phase than `c:forEach`. Here's an [explanation](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat).

`c:forEach` is the way to go here, since this is invoked in view build time.

`ui:repeat` is invoked during view render time, so `p:panel` would have no knowledge of the data being created by `ui:repeat`.

Comment: I have to use ui:repeat because I have to show some dynamic content in this panel with ajax!!! is there any solution

Comment: What do you mean by `dynamic content`, could you show us an example? Your provided example would work perfectly fine with `c:forEach`.

Comment: Ok ,I'm using selectoneMenu to show show details of the selectect item

Comment: <h:outputLabel value="Categorie :"  />  
            <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{composantbean.selectedCategoryId}" required="true" >  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select categorie" itemValue="" />  
                <f:selectItems  value="#{composantbean.listcat}" var="cat" itemValue="#{cat.nomCat}" itemLabel="#{cat.nomCat}" /> 
                <p:ajax update="panlecart2"  event="change" listener="#{composantbean.catListener()}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

Comment: when the user select an item the content of panel is showing according to the selected one ..I have a problem with foreach so I work with repeat

Comment: Could you specify the problem you are experiencing?